# Oracle 10g: Is there a way to build/compile a package using an SQL statement?

Tags: sql, build, oracle10g, package

Conceptually, I'd like to go like:

```
build mypackagename;
```

I know this doesn't exist, but that's the concept I am going for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
alter package [your package name] compile;
```

Comment: Works great!  Even throws an error if the package has issues.